# Email-to-case - Filtering sender email based on record-types

Tags: email, case, record-type, email2case, quickaction

I've configured 2 routing addresses on the Email-to-Case : "Test A" and "Test B".
[image]

And I've assigned them to 2 differents Case recordtypes : "RT Test A" and "RT Test B" :
[image]
[image]

Now I've created a case record, with the record type "RT Test A". The Problem is, I can see all the email-addresses (including the one of recordtype B) on the "From" field of the Quick Action Email:
[image]

Please how can I filter the sender emails, to only see the ones linked to the related recordtype ?

***PS: I'm opened to APEX solution***

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by creating an Email action on the Case object. I then defaulted the "From Address" to the email address required. The one caveat is you can't select ANY other email address - even your own. But your users just want the email sent from a distro at all times - it works.